# Add stops every X miles on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a long trip planned on Google Maps (~1,700 miles). I'm looking for a way to add stops every 500 or so miles to look for spots to stop for the evening.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Route Splitter Tool](http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-split-route.htm) from [Daft Logic](http://daftlogic.com) may be of use to you.

- You click the map to mark your route on and then click the `Make a Split` button.
- You then click the first and second marker that you want to split.
- This drops another marker on to the map which you can drag and drop to the location you want and it will split the route up for you.

It can't split your route up in to 500 mile chunks but you can certainly do this manually.

Comment: Unfortunately, this can't use a route provided by using the "Get Directions" function within Google Maps. Meaning that tracing a route doesn't stick to roads. It's still a helpful tool, thanks!